# Handsontable - Validating cell data depending on the selectOptions available

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am a junior in Handsontable and i have this problem :
My table is completely working, I use on every cells the editor 'select' with different select options. Depending on the cell, the select options are different. But if I copy/paste the value of a cell to another cell (where this paste value isn't part of the select options), it works, and I would actually like the cell to not validate this value.

I made a little example on JsFiddle to make myself understood :
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lenacoco/mgrmppe4/)
If you copy the 'A' on the first row and col, you paste it on a cell of the column C, it works. Even though it shouldn't as the select options of that column are either 'C' or 'D'.
I am pretty sure there is something to do with the cellValidator but I don't know how to proceed. Does anybody have any idea of how to correct this problem..?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I personnaly use in this case is a 'dropdown' column or 'autocomplete' column. Whit those columns types, you can use the additional option 'strict' that can be true or false, and 'allowInvalid' (again, true or false) :

```
columns: [
  {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ['A', 'B'],
    strict: true,
    allowInvalid: false
  },
  {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ['B', 'C', 'D'],
    strict: true,
    allowInvalid: false
  },
  {
    type: 'dropdown',
    source: ['C', 'D'],
    strict: true,
    allowInvalid: false
  }
]
```

From the documentation :

> **strict: *true*** - the autocomplete cells will only accept values that
> are defined in the source array.
>
> [...]
>
> **allowInvalid: *false*** - does not allow manual input of value that does
> not exist in the source. In this case, the ENTER key is ignored and
> the editor field remains opened.

You can find your example edited [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7uLt2gfy/) to see how it works.

Comment: Yes thank you, I actually used dropdown to make it work this way. But if i want the cell to go blank with dropdown, i have to have one of my sources to be of value ' ', which doesn't look very good, but that is not too important for my work.
Thanks for your advice :)